# "pay on" or "pay with"?

Tags: grammar

When I pay for something at grocery or anywhere.

> I will pay on a MasterCard.
>
> I will pay with a MasterCard.

Which is more commonly used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice among your two proposals would be:

> I will pay **with** a MasterCard.

**But** the best would be:

> I will pay **by** credit card.

Answer (score 2):

One common way to say it is:

> I will pay **with** my MasterCard.

However, we might use *on* if we are using the phrasal verb *put on*:

> I will **put it on** my MasterCard.

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/put-on_1#put-on_1__37) lists one entry for *put on* as:

> **put something on something** (*phrasal verb*)
>   to record something in an account so that someone can pay for it later
>
> - *We put the meal on our expense accounts*.

The sentence "Put it on my VISA" is used in an online ESL dialogue entitled [*The Card Gets Declined*](https://www.eslfast.com/robot/topics/bank/bank11.htm):

> A: Your total comes to $36.78.
>   B: Put it on my VISA.

Comment: Hi J.R. may I ask how and what you used to find that specific sentence in that online ESL vocabulary?

Comment: @Kaique - I did a Google search looking for an example usage of "put it on my credit card," and just happened to stumble upon that one. I wasn't even looking for an ESL example per se, but I figured that website would work well for my example.

Comment: I thought you had looked it up on a website like https://www.english-corpora.org/glowbe/

Answer (score 0):

> I will pay with MasterCard.

or

> I will pay with a MasterCard.

I will pay with MasterCard sounds the most normal to me. You could say:

> I will pay on a MasterCard.

More likely you would say:

> I will put it on a MasterCard.

Comment: I vote for 1 and add: I'll use my MasterCard.